# Which ViewController Concept to use?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

i need the following view layout in my application.

the **green** view is the viewport of the ios application.

on the top (the **blue** ones) are views that should be swipeable left and right but only one view (different content) is visible at a time. this views should snap in place if i swipe.

under this, there are more views arranged horizontally (the **orange** ones). this should also snap in place (always centered so that one view is in the grey section) after swiping. here is more than one view visible at a time.

there are concepts like `PageViewController`, `UIScrollView`, `UICollectionView` and so one.

which one to choose for something like this?

Also is it a good idea to add subViewControllers with this layout? A Controller for each of the scroll views?

thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: An image would help tremendously...

Comment: @JackyBoy sorry, added.

Comment: Do you need to sync both views from top and bottom. ie, when an item is selected in top then corresponding thumbnail should be selected and viceversa. What about the edge conditions, when thumbnail is at the edge? How do you plan to show it?

Comment: Buddy i used table view for something like this rotated it 90 degrees and it just saved me from many hassels of using scroll view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Top I would go with a 3 `UIViewController's` `UIView` (depending on the complexity of the objects). If they are simple things I would just add 3 `UIView's` and and handle the logic in the same `UIViewController`. Either putting the 3 inside a `UIScrollView` (with `pagingEnabled`) or you handling the gestures are both valid possibilities. The botton `UIViews` (orange) could be with a `UICollectionView` (so it could handle the memory for you). A `UIScrollView` for the botton, could work, but if you have too many you can have performance issues.

Comment: Don't mistake comment with Answer. This would be my approach. Someone has problems with it.

Comment: i think U answered him to the question. but i guess the down vote was for not answering the 2nd part of the question "Also is it a good idea to add subViewControllers with this layout? A Controller for each of the scroll views?" although ur answer is relevent +1

Comment: I did answer, not directly, but I did: > I would go with a 3 UIViewController's UIView (depending on the complexity of the objects)